# Can I restrict numbers to only 3 decimals globally in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, numbers, ghc

I have a package which generates SVG code (images and icons)

However, the resulting svg code is too large because all numbers have lots of decimal places.

Is there a language pragma or anything similar that I can do to restrict all numbers to only have 3 decimal digits?

I would like to do this with some minimal code, I do not want to apply some function to every `Float` number individually.

Comment: You'll need to give a bit more details to get a concrete answer for how you could achieve your goal. (Only, as amalloy answered, a global pragma is _not_ the way.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't change how IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic works. That change would probably affect a lot more than you expect, anyway. Fortunately, what you want is not to change how floats are represented, but how they are presented. So you only have to change the code that actually writes floats to the output file, not all code that touches floats.

You mention in a comment that you're using blaze-svg to do the rendering. This would have been helpful to include in the question, since its API affects what you can do. I'm not familiar with that package, but at a glance it has a ton of functions with signature

```
foo :: Show a => a -> Markup
```

This is kinda an awkward signature, since `Show a => a` is just a weird way to represent a String. But it means you can't just format the string yourself and then pass it in: you have to pass in something that's `Show`. Of course, String is Show, but if you give it a String it'll call `show` on that String, and wind up wrapping it in `"` characters! Presumably at the moment you are passing in Float values, and the library is rendering them. What you want is a type that acts like Float but with a different Show implementation. That's what newtypes are for:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
newtype ThreeDigitFloat = TDF Float
  -- cut any of these you don't need
  deriving (Num, Eq, Ord, Floating, RealFloat, Fractional, Real, RealFrac)

instance Show ThreeDigitFloat where
  show (TDF x) = _whateverYouWant
```

Then instead of working with Float, you just work with ThreeDigitFloat, and the library will render them as you intend.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I can do that because rendering is done by the package blaze-svg, but I will look into it.

Comment: @RamiroPastor I added a section to the answer about blaze-svg.

Comment: Ok I understand that approach but this is the kind of change I do not want, changing every bit of code of my package, and using my own Float type instead of the common Float found in the prelude. The help is greatly appreciated nevertheless.

Comment: @RamiroPastor You'd only have to change the type signatures, not any of the implementation. So the compiler will make it easy to be sure you got the change right.